# Using an existing API keys(multiple keys) with the Serverless Framework in AWS

Tags: aws-api-gateway, api-key

I have a senario where the api keys are created using terraform. Now we are moving to serverless in second version of the same service. But we dont want to update the keys which we have shared with other teams. Any way of adding multiple existing apis in serverless?

I tried this solution but it doesnot seems to be working with multiple keys.
[Using an existing API key with the Serverless Framework in AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40596182/using-an-existing-api-key-with-the-serverless-framework-in-aws)

Answer (score 0):

In your `serverless.yml` define multiple [AWS::ApiGateway::ApiKey](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-apikey.html) resources. Just ensure the values match your existing keys.

```yaml
resources:
  Resources:
    ExistingKey1:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::ApiKey
      Properties: 
        Enabled: true
        StageKeys: 
          - RestApiId:
              Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
            StageName: ${sls:stage}
        Value: myexistingapikeythatisatleasttwentycharacterslong
      DependsOn: ApiGatewayDeployment${sls:instanceId}
...
```